# Profile c++ program in perf

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler, perf

I am Ubuntu 16.04 user.
For profiling `c++` program I use `perf` tool. So I run:

```
perf record ./myprogram myprogram_args
perf report
```

Now as output I have:

```
  14,52%  CSim2Sim  libsimgrid.so.3.13.90  [.] lmm_solve
   4,40%  CSim2Sim  libsimgrid.so.3.13.90  [.] lmm_update_modified_set_rec
   4,05%  CSim2Sim  libc-2.23.so           [.] _int_malloc
   3,30%  CSim2Sim  libsimgrid.so.3.13.90  [.] simgrid::surf::Model::next_occuring_event_lazy
   2,19%  CSim2Sim  libc-2.23.so           [.] _int_free
........................................................................
```

I see only "depth" and library calls from my program. How can I get report from perf similar to this template? (something like this):

```
  4,52%  CSim2Sim  my_function1(int argc, char* argv[])
  3,52%  CSim2Sim  my_function2(int argc, char* argv[])
  3,52%  CSim2Sim  my_function3(int argc, char* argv[])
  1,52%  CSim2Sim  my_function4(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Probably, you need to compile and link with option `-g`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I've tried it, but everything is the same =(

Comment: Have you tried [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)?

Answer (score 4):

Going from [perf](/questions/tagged/perf) over [info:perf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perf/info) to [Perf Wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), and finally to [Tutorial - Perf Wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Source_level_analysis_with_perf_annotate)

> **Source level analysis with perf annotate**
>   ...
>   perf annotate can generate sourcecode level information if the application is compiled with *-ggdb*. The following snippet shows the much more informative output for the same execution of noploop when compiled with this debugging information.

So compiling (and maybe linking?) with option [`-ggdb`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) should do the trick.

Then you can use [`perf record`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record) to collect runtime information, and later analyze this with `perf annotate`.

---

I just found this answer to [Alternatives to gprof [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958510/1741542). It recommends using gcc's option `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, if you want to get call graph information. So, depending on what you want to achieve and your optimization level, you might need to add this option too.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend using [gprof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html). You'll compile your C (or C++) program by passing `-pg`  (probably also with `-O`....) to `gcc`  and/or `g++`  (perhaps change some `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`  in your `Makefile` ). Read about [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) of GCC.